# Multiple TextBox.Text Values in If statements

Tags: if-statement, textbox, vb6

```
 If Trim(Me.txtLender.Text) = "WARRANTY FINANCE" Or Trim(Me.cmbLender.Text) = "WARRANTY FINANCE" Then
frmWarrantyFinance.Show
 if Trim(Me.txtLender.Text) = "PAYLINK PAYMENT PLANS" Or Trim(Me.cmbLender.Text) = "PAYLINK PAYMENT PLANS" Then
frmWarrantyFinance.Show
End If
```

Is there a more efficient way to word this If statement such as

```
 If (Me.TEXT.text) = "This" or "That" OR (ME.CMB.text) = "This" or "That" Then
 ''Code
```

Comment: how is VB6 related to VS2005? ... use `ElseIf`  or put the IF on a new line as the error msg indicates.  you could also use a CASE statement

Comment: oops didnt mean to put that sorry

Comment: Why the `Else` for if both calling `frmWarrantyFinance.Show` ?

Comment: Yeah, im looking for a more efficient way to write it like the second part of my question, i just dont know the syntax

Comment: no, etaiso is asking why there is an ELSE statement at all since BOTH conditions result in the SAME action

Comment: I guess i should take it out, is there a better way to word this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
Select Case UCase(Trim(Me.txtLender.Text))
    Case "WARRANTY FINANCE", "WARRANTY FINANCE"
        ' Code 1
    Case "PAYLINK PAYMENT PLANS", "PAYLINK PAYMENT PLANS"
        ' Code 2
    Case Else
        ' Code 3
End Select
```

There is no way to do it EXACTLY the way you are asking. If you were simply looking for more efficient way, then you can use `SELECT` statement above.